# Jquery Poptrox HTML Content

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am currently using JQUERY POPTROX: https://github.com/n33/jquery.poptrox

To create my popups. However, currently, what i understand is that this is the syntax:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="path/to/image1.jpg"><img src="path/to/image1_thumbnail.jpg" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="path/to/image2.jpg"><img src="path/to/image2_thumbnail.jpg" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="path/to/image3.jpg"><img src="path/to/image3_thumbnail.jpg" /></a></li>
</ul>
```

However, i was thinking is there a way to make the pop up display HTML content (e.g divs) ferried via ajax rather than images/videos? Thanks!

Comment: Just look at the documentation (README.md or the githubpage you linked), you'll find your answer there.

Comment: i actually found the ajax part, however, on the ahref part, i have to specify the link, im not very sure about what link to actually put, can you enlighten me? thanks!